# that fulcrumed point of sharp intersection

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is "that fulcrumed point of sharp intersection" in the following context?

> My pear had bird’s-egg specklings of a delicacy I’d never before seen on a pear, and seldom on a bird’s egg, either. It wasn’t quite ripe, though; it didn’t have that superb grittiness of skin, when the flesh dissolves and the disintegrating skin grinds against your molars. Apple skin must be chewed heavily and steadily, and even so its slick, sharp-cornered surfaces survive a lot of molaring. But eating a ripe pear is similar to cutting a piece of paper with a pair of scissors: you feel the grit of the cut paper transmitted back through the blades to your fingers, **you can sense that fulcrumed point of sharp intersection**.
>   (Nicholson Baker)

Comment: The author is using* fulcrum*, normally a noun, here as a verb. What he means is the pin holding the blades of the scissors together forms a fulcrum for the levers of the two handles to apply power at the intersection. And that is what is felt.

Answer (score 1):

The author is referring to the point on a pair of scissors where the blades meet.

Comment: Right, a "fulcrum" is a pivot, and with scissors that pivot occurs at the intersection of two sharp edges.